# Concatenate collection of XML tags to string with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm stuck with using a web service I have no control over and am trying to parse the XML returned by that service into a standard object.

A portion of the XML structure looks like this

```
<NO>
   <L>Some text here </L>
   <L>Some additional text here </L>
   <L>Still more text here </L>
</NO>
```

In the end, I want to end up with one String property that will look like **"Some text here Some additional text here Still more text here "**

What I have for an initial pass is what follows.  I think I'm on the right track, but not quite there yet:

```
XElement source = \\Output from the Webservice
List<IndexEntry> result;

result = (from indexentry in source.Elements(entryLevel)
    select new IndexEntry()
    {
        EtiologyCode = indexentry.Element("IE") == null ? null : indexentry.Element("IE").Value,
        //some code to set other properties in this object
        Note = (from l in indexentry.Elements("NO").Descendants
                select l.value)  //This is where I stop
                               // and don't know where to go
    }
```

I know that I could add a ToList() operator at the end of that query to return the collection. Is there an opertaor or technique that would allow me to inline the concatentation of that collection to a single string?

Feel free to ask for more info if this isn't clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ to XML is indeed the way here:

```cs
// Note: in earlier versions of .NET, string.Join only accepts
// arrays. In more modern versions, it accepts sequences.
var text = string.Join(" ", topElement.Elements("L").Select(x => x.Value));
```

EDIT: Based on the comment, it looks like you just need a single-expression way of representing this. That's easy, if somewhat ugly:

```
result = (from indexentry in source.Elements(entryLevel)
    select new IndexEntry
    {
        EtiologyCode = indexentry.Element("IE") == null 
                           ? null 
                           : indexentry.Element("IE").Value,
        //some code to set other properties in this object
        Note = string.Join(" ", indexentry.Elements("NO")
                                          .Descendants()
                                          .Select(x => x.Value))
    };
```

Another alternative is to extract it into a separate extension method (it has to be in a top-level static class):

```cs
public static string ConcatenateTextNodes(this IEnumerable<XElement> elements) =>
    string.Join(" ", elements.Select(x => x.Value));
```

then change your code to:

```
result = (from indexentry in source.Elements(entryLevel)
    select new IndexEntry
    {
        EtiologyCode = indexentry.Element("IE") == null 
                           ? null 
                           : indexentry.Element("IE").Value,
        //some code to set other properties in this object
        Note = indexentry.Elements("NO")
                         .Descendants()
                         .ConcatenateTextNodes()
    }
```

**EDIT: A note about efficiency**

Other answers have suggested using `StringBuilder` in the name of efficiency. I would check for evidence of this being the right way to go before using it. If you think about it, `StringBuilder` and `ToArray` do similar things - they create a buffer bigger than they need to, add data to it, resize it when necessary, and come out with a result at the end. The hope is that you won't need to resize too often.

The *difference* between `StringBuilder` and `ToArray` here is what's being buffered - in `StringBuilder` it's the entire contents of the string you've built up so far. With `ToArray` it's *just* references. In other words, resizing the internal buffer used for `ToArray` is likely to be cheaper than resizing the one for `StringBuilder`, *particularly* if the individual strings are long.

After doing the buffering in `ToArray`, `string.Join` is hugely efficient: it can look through *all* the strings to start with, work out *exactly* how much space to allocate, and then concatenate it without ever having to copy the actual character data.

This is in [sharp contrast to a previous answer I've given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster/585897#585897) - but unfortunately I don't think I ever wrote up the benchmark.

I certainly wouldn't expect `ToArray` to be significantly slower, and I think it makes the code simpler here - no need to use side-effects etc, aggregation etc.

Comment: Jon, maybe my example isn't clear.  I'm populating a more complex opject with a LINQ TO XML query. The example only represents a portion of the XML involved. So in my bottom example NOTE represents a string property in my object, and I would like, if possible to populate it...

Comment: ...inline with the rest of the LINQ query I have in place.  Am I being clear?  I see what you're advocating and understand it, I'm just not sure how to apply it in my situation.  I could add more code for context if that would help.

Comment: Jon. Thanks for the expanded answer.  Really glad I went to lunch before I started banging on this.

Comment: Jon.  I don't have enough rep to edit your answer.  For future clarity, please fix a small typo.  In the extension method definition "string values = " should be "string[] values = "

Thanks.

Comment: Just glad to do my part in advancing the cause that is Jon Skeet :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with it myself, but it strikes me that [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) could vastly simplify your code. Do a select of XML document, then loop through it and use a StringBuilder to append the L element to some string.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use Aggregate()

```
var q = topelement.Elements("L")
                  .Select(x => x.Value)
                  .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
                             (sb, x) => return sb.Append(x).Append(" "),
                             sb => sb.ToString().Trim());
```

**edit**: The first lambda in Aggregate is the *accumulator*.  This is taking all of your values and creating one value from them.  In this case, it is creating a StringBuilder with your desired text.  The second lambda is the *result selector*.  This allows you to translate your accumulated value into the result you want.  In this case, changing the StringBuilder to a String.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  You'd have to replace 'var q =' with 'Note = ' in your code, btw.

Comment: See my expanded answer - I don't think using a StringBuilder is likely to improve the performance over using string.Join and ToArray together. It may even make it worse. It certainly makes it more complicated IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is shorter and more readable except for the Aggregate() which is complicated.

Comment: @ATL_DEV: Given that the Aggregate call is half of the code, I'd say that's enough to say it's less readable overall. These days there's no need for the ToArray call in my answer, either - I'll edit that.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Everytime I see your name, I can't help but think of the hit song from many years back, "Get Low" by Lil Jon & The Eastside Boyz. There's a catchy chorus where Lil Jon hollers  "'Til all skeet-skeet...'Til all skeet-skeet." It's as if Lil Jon is a closet c# programmer who was inspired to write the song after reading your book.

Answer (score 0):

I like LINQ as much as the next guy, but you're reinventing the wheel here.  The `XmlElement.InnerText` property does exactly what's being asked for.

Try this:

```
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
        string xml =
            @"<NO>
  <L>Some text here </L>
  <L>Some additional text here </L>
  <L>Still more text here </L>
</NO>";
        d.LoadXml(xml);
        Console.WriteLine(d.DocumentElement.InnerText);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be all well and good, but I'm parsing XML with LINQ to build a business object and in a number of cases I need to build collections inside those objects from similar constructs in the XML, so rather than extra processing later I want to keep this inside the existing LINQ query.