# Optimize loop in ASP.Net / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization

I wrote a loop to display each line one by one from a List of string.
The problem is that the list contains more that 45,000 lines and its taking a lot of time to create the page for displaying.

Can someone please help in optimizing the code !

```
        List<string> OverrrideLog = lc.getOverrideLog();
        List<string> AccessLog = lc.getAccessLog();

        foreach (string s in OverrrideLog)
            lblOverrideLog.Text += s + "<br/>";

        foreach (string s in AccessLog)
            lblAccessLog.Text += s + "<br/>";
```

Here lblOverrideLog and lblAccessLog are literals and each list has more than 22,000 lines.

Comment: use a `StringBuilder`!

Comment: use `String.Join Method (String, String[])`

Comment: @CD No, `String.Join Method (String, IEnumerable<String>). He already has a `List`

Comment: xanatos: yes, you are right..

Comment: read this article
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/StringBuilder_vs_String.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) Method (String, IEnumerable):

```
List<string> OverrrideLog = lc.getOverrideLog();
List<string> AccessLog = lc.getAccessLog();

lblOverrideLog.Text = String.Join("<br />", OverrrideLog);
lblAccessLog.Text = String.Join("<br />", AccessLog);
```

(See also [String.Join vs. StringBuilder: which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster))

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
I used this one and the one answered by SBlackler. Both are working great !

Comment: Admittedly, I didn't know about `String.Join` in this way +1

Answer (score 4):

Untested but try this:

```
List<string> OverrrideLog = lc.getOverrideLog();
List<string> AccessLog = lc.getAccessLog();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var el in OverrrideLog)
{
  sb.Append(el);
  sb.Append(" <br />");
}

foreach(var el in AccessLog)
{
  sb2.Append(el);
  sb2.Append(" <br />");
}

lblOverrideLog.Text = sb.ToString();
lblAccessLog.Text = sb2.ToString();
```

Edit:

woops, put `val` instead of `var`

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I used this one and the one answered by CD. Both are working great

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Concatenating strings like you are creates thousands of temporary ones in memory.

Comment: George, sorry: I red your comment and started to write an answer... but you are the first, so do you prefer I delete my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

for a exsample

```
            OverrrideLog.ForEach(x=>{
                if (sbOverrideLog.Length > 0)
                    sbOverrideLog.Append("<br />");

                sbOverrideLog.Append(x);
            });

            AccessLog.ForEach(x =>
            {
                if (sbAccessLog.Length > 0)
                    sbAccessLog.Append("<br />");

                sbAccessLog.Append(x);
            });
```