# string.Join throws OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, .net, string, exception

I have a list of strings and I want to join them with " "(space) between them, so I use the [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) method:

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{        
    var strings = lines.Where(l => l.Code == line.Code).Select(l => l.Data);
    var original = string.Join(" ", strings);        
}
```

Data looks something like this: "123456789, 987654321, 32132, 7873892 ..."

But I get an OutOfMemoryException. Why? each string is approximatly 100-150 characters and there are 5-10 strings in the list.

Is there a better way then the string.Join?

Comment: What else is the program doing? This might just be the thing that pushes you over the edge.

Comment: Can you post the strings you are trying to join?

Comment: There must be something else going on (loop, recursion, etc).  We need to see the full code or the exception stack trace.

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but original isn't a reference to one of the strings in `strings`, is it?

Comment: my guess: this is in the middle of a `for` / `foreach` / `do` loop

Comment: @Oded, sorry it was typing error, I deleted the +. again,sorry

Comment: @JonathanRich - Can't be as `original` is declared on that line.

Comment: @Oded It was originally `original += ...`, the OP must have updated his code sample.

Comment: @JonathanRich - it was originally `var original +=` which looked very strange. But as Christopher commented, we need more code.

Comment: is `strings` a standard array or list or is it a more complicated type from an external library or one of your own? Perhaps the enumerator is doing something silly.

Comment: How many lines in lines? How much text are you reading?

Comment: @Oded 20 lines. each data is 100-150 chars, do you see recursion here?

Comment: This is doing lots of extra work. If every line has a code of 1, then you are doing this join operation n times and each loop does a where that collects every line. Even though each iteration produces the exact same result.

Comment: What is the type of `lines`? Could iterating over it be the real source of the issue?

Comment: @gdoron: Support your assertion with facts. There is obviously something mysterious going on here.

Comment: @gdoron How does the line class (with the `Code` and `Data` properties) look?

Comment: @Magnus, simple properties only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (and let us know if you get the same error):

```
lines.GroupBy(l => l.Code).Select(l => string.Join(" ", l.Select (x => x.Data)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var line in lines.GroupBy(p=>p.Code))
{        
    var original = string.Join(" ", line.Select(p=>p.Data));        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The StringBuild() class can join strings and isn't immutable.

Here's an MSDN article talking about immutable string vs how StringBuilder works.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'm not curious as to what this has to do with gdoron's question.

Comment: @Raskolnikov He asked "Is there a better way then the string.Join?" My answer was SringBuilder. The OutOfMemory could be caused by a million unrelated things. My understanding is that StringBuilder is the suggested method by MS to concatenate a bunch of strings. I don't think my suggestion was completely off-topic?!

Comment: @JonC: (I'm not the downvoter either) `String.Join()` is actually more efficient than `StringBuilder` because it can determine the lengths before-hand and build the exact sized buffer.

Comment: @JonC `String.Join` can actually be faster than `StringBuilder` see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare I've read that as well but it always says "in some scenarios" I'm not sure if that fits the OPs scenario but saying StringBuilder as an alternative for string.join I would not think deserves a down vote?

Comment: @JonC: I understand and accept your explanation. Also I noticed that I said "I'm not curious as to...". No idea what happened there, but I guess my question was obvious with the context.

Comment: @JonC: I'm not the down-voter, so I don't know why he was down-voted.  Sometimes that happens unfortunately and you never know who or why.  Sometimes, unfortunately, it's even a petty attempt by some answers to push their answer up the list, but that's *really* rare.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare No worries. I'm here to payback for the help I get from SO, not so much for "points". I just don't want to be a leech really. It would just help if someone told me what I was doing wrong with a downote.

Comment: @JonC: I know, I really wish there was a place for a downvote comment (even if anonymous).  I know they can put it in the comments, of course, but often they don't.