# Stringbuilder ignores last space

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

I am initialising a `StringBuilder` as follows:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Symptoms are ");
```

After this I loop through a list and add each string item to the end using

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    builder.Append(item);
}
```

An example `item` would be something like "headache" but once i've appended it to "Symptoms are " and called `builder.ToString()` it shows:

```
"Symptoms areHeadache...etc"
```

as opposed to

```
"Symptoms are Headache...etc"
```

Why is it ignoring the space?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this issue. Would you post a small but complete program that produces the problem?

Comment: `var builder = new StringBuilder("Symptoms are "); builder.Append("Headache"); var result = builder.ToString();` result is `"Symptoms are Headache"`. Can't reproduce.

Comment: If you manually add items with `.append()` outside of the `foreach` do you see the problem?

Comment: My test code works fine:             `var sb = new StringBuilder("abc ");
            var list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                sb.Append(item);
            }` -- Produces "abc 123"

Comment: Are you calling Trim anywhere?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if he's actually talking about a lack of whitespace between the _items_... in which case he ought to use something like `String.Format("Symptoms are {0}.", String.Join(", ", items))`

Comment: I imagine all this is only making @UweKeim's headache worse. Hopefully the OP can clarify this mess. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code you've provided doesn't produce the problem you've described, I'm guessing that your *actual* problem is a lack of whitespace between the symptoms (items). In that case, I'd suggest using [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx) like so:

```
var output = String.Format("Symptoms are {0}.", String.Join(", ", items));
```

Now your items will be comma-separated with a padding space between.

Comment: But your solution o/p : 'Symptoms are A, B, C' But Actual output should be 'Symptoms are A B C'

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi He can provide whatever delimiter he'd like for `String.Join()`. He's not providing _any_ delimiter at the moment. (And it's actually `"Symptoms are A, B, C."` because I took some liberties with formatting.)

Comment: You are suggesting String.Format, What is the wrong with AppendFormat ???

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi Because you've proposed calling `AppendFormat()` for each item in the collection... while I've called `String.Format` and `String.Join` only once. Also check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster

Answer (score 0):

It does not need to eat the space on other PCs.   Maybe try a new PC.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Symptoms are ");
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "headache", "corrupt memory" };

foreach(var item in list)
{
        builder.Append(item);
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```