# Is StringBuilder only preferred in looping scenarios?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I understand that `StringBuilder` is the choice for concatenating strings in a loop, like this:

```
List<string> myListOfString = GetStringsFromDatabase();
var theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(string myString in myListOfString)
{
    theStringBuilder.Append(myString);
}

var result = theStringBuilder.ToString();
```

But what are the scenarios where `StringBuilder` outperforms `String.Join()` or vice versa?

```
var theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
theStringBuilder.Append("Is this ");
theStringBuilder.Append("ever a good ");
theStringBuilder.Append("idea?");

var result = theStringBuilder.ToString();
```

OR

```
string result = String.Join(" ", new String[]
            {
                "Or", "is", "this", "a", "better", "solution", "?"
            });
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Is there a threshold where the creation overhead of the `StringBuilder` is not worth it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster

Similar post, not exactly the same

Comment: All I know (which was acknowleged in the question) is that stringbuilder blows concatenation out of the water (Cut one scheduled task of mine from about 3 hours to 5 minutes)

Comment: @DanDrews what the hell task were you doing?!

Comment: @Jonesy: Heavy looping, probably.

Comment: @Jonesy I was parsing lots of XML from a DB and because of this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310378 I had to loop through thousands of rows (because they were huge XML files) to concatenate them into one large string. I had been using concatenation rather than StringBuilder and I repeat this 30 times for the task

Unfortunately, we have a framework setup that I had to use so I couldn't use execute XML reader, but switching to stringbuilder made it quick enough

Comment: Rule of thumb for me is, if there's a framework method that does the job, use that as it'll invariably be optimized for the scenario (using a SB internally or pre-allocating a string etc.). In this case, Join fits your criteria so I'd run with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems `string.Join` uses `StringBuilder` under the hood from the code (Reflector):

```
public static string Join(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    using (IEnumerator<string> enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return Empty;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = StringBuilderCache.Acquire(0x10);
        if (enumerator.Current != null)
        {
            sb.Append(enumerator.Current);
        }
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            sb.Append(separator);
            if (enumerator.Current != null)
            {
                sb.Append(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
        return StringBuilderCache.GetStringAndRelease(sb);
    }
}
```

So in your scenario, it does not different much. But I would prefer using `StringBuilder` when trying to concat string based on the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

String.Join has several overloads. Some of them takes `string[]` and other takes `IEnumerable<string>`. If you see the source code of them you will notice that they are implemented differently.

For array case String.Join first calculate the total number of characters then allocate a string of that size.

But for `IEnumarable` case it just use `StringBuilder.Append` inside.

So if you have array of string then probably String.Join is faster than `StringBuilder.Append` but for IEnumarable case performance is same.

For all cases I will suggest to use `String.Join` as it requires less code.

Answer (score -1):

`StringBuilder` will outperform string operations in most scenarios when it comes to memory usage.

I routinely use `StringBuilder` to build full logging information as I need to join pieces of information from multiple sources.

Jeff Atwood's [The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html) could be is a good read too.

Comment: Could the person downvoting explain their reasoning?