# Write "Hello" multiple times in the same line

Tags: c#

How would you define a method that returns

> "[Number of times]: hello hello hello [repeat Number of times]";

I want it to put in hello as many times my input wants it to display.

So, "number of times" is going to be there but i dont know how to do the hello.

My suggestion is,

```
return $"number of times: {string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("hello", num))}";
```

But the problem I get here is that there is no space between the hello's.

Could you help me please?  I have been searching for hours but can't find a similar answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there, use String.Join instead of String.Concat, which allows you to add `" "` as a separator between elements

```cs
return $"number of times: {string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat("hello", num))}";
```

Comment: Thank you mate! it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The String object is immutable. Every time you use one of the methods in the System.String class, you create a new string object in memory, which requires a new allocation of space for that new object. In situations where you need to perform repeated modifications to a string, the overhead associated with creating a new String object can be costly. The System.Text.StringBuilder class can be used when you want to modify a string without creating a new object.

so I recommend this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder($"number of times: {num} = hello");

for (int i = 0; i < num-1; i++) sb.Append( ", hello");

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

result for num=12

```
number of times: 12 = hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/585897/832052

Comment: I would say specifically the immutability of string should be brought up wrt the Enumerable.Repeat, not String.Join

Comment: @djv Yes, It is true. But in this case ,  there is no array, it is created and after this join is used. Even if  .Join uses a string builder, direct way to use  a string builder is always better.