# This is my first time using C#.Can anyone suggest me any better way or a optimized code of mine

Tags: c#

this snippet gets a list from user and displays it.Can anyone tell how to display all the elements in a list in single line.

```
        List<string> numbersInput = new List<string>();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer: ");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input1))
        {
            numbersInput.Add(input1);
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
            input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (numbersInput.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + numbersInput.Count + " numbers, they were: ");
            var a = 1;
            foreach (var input in numbersInput)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number " + a++ + " = \t" + input);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered 0 numbers.");
        }
```

Comment: Look at `Console.Write` since that doesn't make a new line every time.

Comment: Try, instead of that foreach loop you have there, `Console.WriteLine("Numbers: " + string.Join(", ", numbersInput));`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: Using Linq, instead of writing `numbersInput.Count > 0` you can write `numbersInput.Any()`

Comment: Also _"best/better"_ might be _subject to opinion_ and if so is sadly off-topic for SO. [ask].  Consider re-phrasing your question to be [constructive subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer: ");
string line;

while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    numbersInput.Add(line);
    
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
}

Comment: @MickyD it's definitely partially code improvement/review but there was also the question of "how to get console text to output onto a single line" - not the best question and almost certainly answered before; but not entirely off-topic for SO

Comment: Whilst the question's _body_ did report a bug, it was buried and not mentioned in the title.  As mentioned it probably would have been better if the OP rephrased their question because the title on its own is not [constructive subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  Because the OP's question wasn't _constructive subjective_ whereby _["...insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references..."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_ inevitably leads to people posting answers with unjustified conclusions or unproven claims.

Comment: Ajay, consider posting your question again but focusing on the fact that your current code is outputting to **multiple lines** but _you want a single-line output_.  Best not to mention _"better"_ and _"optimized"_

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options:

`Console.WriteLine()` outputs whatever string you give it and starts a new line of text after it - akin to when we type and press the enter key.

`Console.Write()` outputs whatever string you give it - no more, and no less.

So you could simply replace the `WriteLine` in the loop with a `Write`...

Or you could build the entire string and pass it to a `WriteLine()`, something like:

```
List<string> numbersInput = new List<string>();

Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer: ");
string input1 = Console.ReadLine();

while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input1))
{
   numbersInput.Add(input1);
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
   input1 = Console.ReadLine();
}

if (numbersInput.Count > 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + numbersInput.Count + " numbers, they were: ");
   var a = 1;
   var s = "";
   foreach (var input in numbersInput)
   {
      s = $"{s}, Number {a++} = \t{input}"; //string interpolation only applicable post C# 7
   }
   Console.WriteLine(s.Trim(", "));
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("You have entered 0 numbers.");
}
```

In the comments, Lasse suggests `Console.WriteLine("Numbers: " + string.Join(", ", numbersInput));` (instead of the `foreach` loop) which would potentially be more efficient... but would have a different output format to your original question.

Alternatively, if you want to maintain the output format of your question, you could rejig things to use a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`. For instance:

```
Dictionary<string, string> numbersInput = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer: ");
string input1 = Console.ReadLine();

var x = 1;
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input1))
{
   //numbersInput.Add(input1);
   numbersInput.Add(input1, $"Number {x} = \t{input1}");
   x++;
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
   input1 = Console.ReadLine();
}

if (numbersInput.Count > 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + numbersInput.Count + " numbers, they were: ");
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbersInput.Values));
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("You have entered 0 numbers.");
}
```

Comment: Shoot, you caught me - brain overtook my hands; was supposed to be "which would potentially be more efficient". I'll just edit that in

Comment: Some interesting stuff at [String.Join vs. StringBuilder: which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster) by the two titans Mr Skeet and Mr Gravell.  Anyway, don't want to be a nag so here's +1  :)

Comment: Yeah, if it was the weekend I'd go down the rabbithole but this a "I need a break from work work" answer haha